# Detect iPad in portrait orientation with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have some jQuery, but want it only to run when the iPad is in portrait mode, hover the iPad (in landscape mode) processes the script...

```
var portraitWidth = $(window).width(); //detect the iPad in Portrait orientation
    if (portraitWidth < 769) {
        $('.model-selector h2:first-child').toggle(function () {
            $(this).parent().animate({
                top: '-138px'
            }, 250);
        }, function () {
            $('.model-selector').animate({
                top: '-45px'
            }, 250);
        });
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score -1):

I had same issue. innerWidth() worked for me I think because .width() would only test for the device's actual width which doesn't change....